# How do I test password protected files in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am working on a script that will search through a linux directory (starting from root) and identify specific files based on file extensions. I want to dump those into a new text file (ex. testFile.txt) and then run each of the files (based on file path) against a list of generic passwords to ensure strong password use. I created a bunch of test directories and dummy files with the needed extensions and my search script works perfectly. I am able to successfully find all the correct files and put them into a testFile.txt, however, I'm not sure where to begin when it comes to testing for password protected files...any suggestions would be appreciated. I have included the script that I have written so far below:

```
#!/bin/bash

#This script, in theory, should search an entire linux instance for files with extensions
#.p12, .jks, .pfx, .pem, .ppk. Any found files will be saved to a text doc. For each file in said
#doc, we will attempt to open the file with a list of generic passwds. If there are any
#successes, we will save that file and the passwd to a different flag doc to be addressed.

#This should search a named directory for the file extensions and save to output file
find / -name *.p12 -o -name *.jks > keytoolFile.txt

#As a test, iterate over the output file and name them

keyFile=$(cat keytoolFile.txt)

for line in $keyFile; do
   echo -e "$line\n"
    keytool -list -keystore $line
done

#This next bit should go through the next set of file extensions and test them
find / -name *.pfx -o -name *.pem -o -name *.ppk > sshFile.txt

textFile=$(cat sshFile.txt)

for line in $textFile; do
    echo -e "$line\n"
    ssh-keygen -y -f $line
done
```

**EDIT**

I have added additions to the code above in an attempt to improve it, however, I am still having issues trying to add logic. What I want it to do is to run the command (depending on the file extension) which should prompt for a password. The passwords to be tested will be stored in a separate text file and I want the script to loop through each password in an attempt to find one that works. If it successfully authenticates then I want it to dump the file path and the password into a final text document.

Right now it asks for the password to be entered manually and on a failed attempt it simply moves on. Any tips on how I should add this logic would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash

#This script, in theory, should search an entire linux instance for files with extensions
#.p12, .jks, .pfx, .pem, .ppk. Any found files will be saved to a text doc. For each file in said
#doc, we will attempt to open the file with a list of generic passwds. If there are any
#successes, we will save that file and the passwd to a different flag doc to be addressed.

#This should search a named directory for the file extensions and save to output file
find / -name *.p12 -o -name *.jks > keytoolFile.txt

#As a test, iterate over the output file and name them

keyFile=$(cat keytoolFile.txt)
passFile=$(cat pass.txt)

for i in $keyFile; do
   for j in $passFile; do
      echo -e "Attempting $j on $i"
      keytool -list -keystore $line -storepass $j
    done
done

#This next bit should go through the next set of file extensions and test them
find / -name *.pfx -o -name *.pem -o -name *.ppk > sshFile.txt

hostFile=$(cat sshFile.txt)
passFile=$(cat pass.txt)

for i in $hostFile; do
   for j in $passFile; do
      echo -e "Attempting $j on $i"
      ssh-keygen -f -y $i -P $j
   done
done
```

My issue now is that I get an 'Illegal option' error during the keytool operation...it appears to be iterating over the password just fine, but is somehow continuously picking up the first password in the file and trying to pass it as an option somehow...

```
Attempting 1qaz)OKM2wsx(IJN on <path/to/file/file.p12
Illegal option:  1qaz!QAZ2wsx@WSX
```

Comment: a tool like hashcat can bruteforce or use dictionaries to attempt to crack lots of hashed passwords or encrypted files.   it supports a large list of formats you can see here: https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=hashcat

Comment: If you have files named `a.p12` and `b.p12` in the directory from which you run that `find` command, it will generate an error since the `-name *.p12` argument will expand to `-name a.p12 b.12` You need to quote the `*` and write `-name '*.p12'` or similar.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thank you for the advice, I'll make sure to update that.

Comment: Not all of the file extensions you have listed make use of passwords to begin with. You may want to work at this problem from the other direction. It may be easier to search for each format and find one command that does something with it that would first require a password (like printing info about the file). You can then try running that command for each file and see if it succeeds when you pass it the password as input. Odds are if you get a password wrong it will give you a non-zero status code which you can check in for in your script.

Comment: @toppk I'm embarrassed to say that I've never used hashcat before so I was attempting to run this using a text file of generically bad passwords mixed with a few that should work to see if my script would recognize a success and then flag / output the file and password that succeeded.

Comment: @Locke Thank you that was really helpful! I never thought of it that way, but I will start trying to look at it like that.

Comment: you can feed hashcat a list of passwords to try, it can even do variations like try replacing 'a' with '4' or other.  the advantage of hashcat, is that you don't need to figure out how to test each password protected file, and script that, just give hashcat a dictionary list to try and the file you want to guess the password.  (the other advantage is that it can use GPUs for the attack, but that is a different matter :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it that way.  Th are are too many issues that crop up when trying to read a list of names from a file (eg, if any of the names contains an embedded newline, it's hard to distinguish that from 2 distinct names).  Instead, just create a script that tests the files individually and invoke it from find.  Eg, if you put your script in `/path/to/validate`, you can do:

```
find "$HOME" \( -name '*.p12 '-o -name '*.jks' -o -name '*.pfx' \
    -o -name '*.pem' -o -name '*.ppk' \) -exec /path/to/validate {} \;
```

Comment: If one uses `-print0` one can reliably save a list of names to a file :), but yes, this is likewise safe.